# How to read excel file in R that have multiple tables in 1 sheet

Tags: r, excel

I have 3 Excel sheets that includes data from a questionnaire. 1 sheet include 4 tables, like this (just an example):

```
sex Q1 Q2  name etc. 
F   1   1  X
M   2   1  A
M   1   2  B
F   2   2  C
sex Q1  Q2 name etc.
F   1   1   X
M   1   1   B
etc.
```

So in one sheet there are 4 tables after each other. I need to read these files in R, and R need to divide those files. I have 1 file, with 3 sheets that each contains this structure.

Comment: Hi Hellihansen. I've removed the second question from your question. Asking one question at a time will help people to answer clearly, and will help other people who might have the same question if future to find the help they need.

Comment: Do the tables all have the same column names, and are the columns aligned? If you only have three Excel sheets, might it be quickest to tidy the data manually in Excel?

Comment: Iirc, most Excel-reading packages allow you to specify cell-ranges when reading. Which package/function have you tried?

Comment: Why does this need to be done in R? This is a simple task in powerquery

Comment: @CaptainHat Yes the column names are the same. How can I do that?